# How to connect windows client to Tandem Pathway servers via TCP/IP

Tags: sockets, tcp, hp-nonstop, tandem

I have a **Java client** and a **Tandem socket server program**. I am able to connect to the server using the client but I want to configure the server program in a Tandem Pathway environment.

Can someone help me to configure the Tandem server program in a Tandem pathway environment?

I have very basic knowledge of the Tandem Pathway environment and its objects and processes. It will be helpful if someone can provide me with some working examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new server to a running Pathway environment by configuring a new server class which uses your program. Do this either with Pathcom commands or using a GUI with Pathway support (for example in TOP use svrClass>Add dialog).

Note: After you have added the server definition it will disappear if the Pathway is cold-started, so remember to add the configuration commands to the startup file. Again a GUI will typically let you save off the current state as a configuration. Your site may have a macro that does the same.

Assuming that you are doing this from the command line not a GUI, then open the Pathway environment that you are adding the server to with Pathcom, for example:

```
PATHCOM $PATH
```

Then enter your configuration commands for the new server. Example:

```
  RESET SERVER
  SET SERVER PROCESSTYPE GUARDIAN
  SET SERVER AUTORESTART 0
  SET SERVER CPUS (0:1)
  SET SERVER CREATEDELAY 1 MINS
  SET SERVER DEBUG OFF
  SET SERVER DELETEDELAY 10 MINS
  SET SERVER HIGHPIN OFF
  SET SERVER HOMETERM $ZHOME
  SET SERVER LINKDEPTH 1
  SET SERVER MAXLINKS 3
  SET SERVER MAXSERVERS 1
  SET SERVER NUMSTATIC 1
  SET SERVER OWNER 110,102
  SET SERVER PARAM SOMETHING1 "some-value"
  SET SERVER PARAM SOMETHING2 "something"
  SET SERVER PRI 139
  SET SERVER PROCESS $MYSRV
  SET SERVER PROGRAM $VOL.SUBVOL.MYPROG
  SET SERVER SECURITY "N"
  SET SERVER TMF OFF
  SET SERVER VOLUME $VOL.SUBVOL
ADD SERVER MYSERV
```

See the ADD SERVER and SET SERVER commands in the [HP NonStop TS/MP System Management Manual](http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=4201311&docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c02186509).

Control the server class with START SERVER, FREEZE SERVER, STOP SERVER, THAW SERVER commands, again these are documented in the manual.

Comment: Thanks, my server is now up and running in the pathway environment. Also is there any way to see what my server is writing to the HOMETERM i.e. $ZHOME.

Comment: $ZHOME writes to the system console, so you can go and look there if you have access. The alternative is to use an event collector and then view the messages on that.

Comment: Again I'll assume that you are not using a GUI for this. Check that you have a process $0 on your system (status $0 from TACL). This is normally the system's main event collector process. If you are on a development system, then its probably OK to use this. Replace $ZHOME with $0 in your Pathway configuration and restart your server. To view the events you should be able to run a command like this from TACL: `emsdist/name $dist/type p, collector $0, textout $home`    There will me a heap of messages from other processes, but filtering those is off topic for this.